# Example 20: Learn Python the hard way

Tags: python

I was trying to find information on what += does in Python but couldn't find anything that satisfied me. In the study drills for example 20 he asks you to rewrite the script using +=. Even just a small example of what it does or what it can replace would be helpful. How could I rewrite this?

```
from sys import argv

script, input_file = argv

def print_all(f):
    print f.read()

def rewind(f):
    print f.seek(0)

def print_a_line(line, f):
    print line, f.readline()

print "Here is the file: %r" % input_file

current_file = open(input_file)

print_all(current_file)

print "Now let's start from the beginning..."

rewind(current_file)

print "Here are the first three lines of the file:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
current_line = current_line + 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)

current_file.close()
```

Comment: `n += 1` is equivalent to `n = n + 1`

Answer (score 2):

The `+=` operator means to add something to the existing variable. `n += 2` is the same as `n = n + 2`

In your example, instead of `current_line = current_line + 1` , do `current_line += 1`

Comment: Had a typo there, my bad

Answer (score 0):

It literally explains what `+=` means on this page.

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex20.html

> Q: What is `+=`?
>
> A: You know how in English I can rewrite "it is" as "it's"? Or I can rewrite "you are" as "you're"? In English this is called a contraction, and this is kind of like a contraction for the two operations `=` and `+`. That means `x = x + y` is the same as `x += y`.

Answer (score 0):

+= is [Syntactic Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). You can think of Syntactic Sugar as a little extra that makes something just a little easier, or more clear.

This particular piece of Syntactic Sugar is used to add a value (the value to the right, also known as the rvalue) to an existing variable (The variable on the left, also known as the lvalue).

You could write

```
variable += 1
```

as

```
variable = variable + 1
```

and to the interpreter its no different. You can also do the same with other operators.

```
var -= 8   # Subtracting
var *= 3   # Multiplication
var %= 2   # Modulus (Remainder of division)
var /= 4   # Division
```

Or you could simply not. Whatever you think makes your code clear, easy to understand, and easier to type. It's really a preference. I usually do try to stick to one type or another as using multiple programming styles tend to confuse.

Comment: No different? Compare `timeit('a = a + [0]', 'a = []')` with a `+=` version.

Comment: @StefanPochmann - Probably means "no different for primitive variables"

Comment: Optimization is overrated. The time of the programmer is almost always more valuable. You should rarely think about making your code faster unless given a very good reason. Most compilers/interpreters can do this for you far better then you can. I would like to see a comparison of .pyc examples as that has already undergone the optimization.

Comment: @NickYoung Not sure whether you're serious. Did you actually try my example or did you ignore it because you think you know better? In any case, the point wasn't optimization but demonstrating that clearly there is an actual difference. The two statements can do **entirely different** things.

Comment: Well, given that you answered just a few minutes after my question, I'm  rather certain that you didn't try my example. Because on my PC, it would take about **80 minutes** (compared to **0.0036 seconds** for the `+=` version). But again, the point wasn't optimization but showing that clearly different things are happening.

Comment: I was not attempting to ignore anything. I don't happen to have a interpreter at my current employer and was simply commenting on optimization in an assumption (which may be wrong).

Comment: Can you provide how they are different? I would like something so I can be sure the time is not because of how timeit deals with it (Maybe evals?) and rather is how Python deals with the actual code. I trust your answer (I am unsure) but just need clarification so we can ensure we are indeed giving someone the right information in the future.

Comment: Go [here](https://repl.it/BdFr/1), click "run" and watch the right side.

Comment: There goes your *"I don't have an interpreter here"* excuse, btw :-D

Comment: Just realized a much simpler example: `a=b=[]; a=a+[1]; print(b)`. That prints `[]`. With `+=`, it prints `[1]`.